# I am try use routing concept

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I am try use routing concept.I want to show url accoding to page.all pages are created by dynamic. Everypage have it's own unique id.I know about basic concerpt

I am adding global.asax file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);

}
void  RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{

    routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "home1", "~/default.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "home2", "~/default2.aspx");


}
```

and C# coading

```
   RouteValueDictionary para = new RouteValueDictionary { {"","" } };
   VirtualPathData abc = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null,"home",para);
   hyper.NavigateUrl = abc.VirtualPath;
```

My question is how i get the page id from database and where i can pass this value...

Comment: One thing more ,I have to know if i add another page it's automatically fetch the value from database or i have all another function on global file

Comment: anyone there to help me