# Routing issue in asp.net not able to implement dynamic routing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I know about static routing.but not able to implement dynamic routing.ex www.shp.com/default.aspx?cat=1-p20 that i need this look like this www.shp.com/product/productname .

So how can i fetch the data from database , how to pass this value to query string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean this, but you can create dynamic routes using something like /controler/action{youVar}

Answer (score 0):

You need to define routes in the global.asax
The route you need is of the format: www.shp.com/product/{productname}
The product name can be obtained in the page using the Page.RouteData.Values collection

Here's a primer on how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thnx journey for help  , but i have no id how can i implement plz see this ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944852/guys-i-am-try-use-routing-concept.  I want to get value from database me question is i have to store value in variable after that use or it will get automatically value from database.  :(